# Django filter current month data

Tags: python, django

I want to filter current month data. I tried this.

```
this_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
products = Product.objects.filter(date_added__month=this_month)
```

But, this only works with `USE_TZ = False` . if I change to `USE_TZ = True` . my filter query not working.

model

```
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Is "this_month" different depending on USE_TZ?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now()` does not contain any timezone data. Try using `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty old question, but I think my answer can help people searching for it.

First of all, when USE_TZ=True, we should always use `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now()`. ([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects))

Django documentation [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#month):

> When USE_TZ is True, datetime fields are converted to the current time
> zone before filtering. This requires time zone definitions in the
> database.

It also give [instruction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#database-time-zone-definitions) to install time zone definition to database:

> SQLite: install `pytz` — conversions are actually performed in Python.

> PostgreSQL: no requirements (see Time Zones).

> Oracle: no requirements (see Choosing a Time Zone File).

> MySQL: install `pytz` and load the time zone tables with [`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).

In my case : mysql and Mac Os, following command solve the problem:

```
sudo mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql -u root mysql
```

Now I can use `<datetime>__month` filter even if `USE_TZ = True`

Do comment if you need further explanation.

### edit

added info about django.utils.timezone on suggestion of [Jerzyk yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646765/jerzyk)

Comment: for the answer completness, please add info, to use django.utils.timezone.now() for the current date-time when using timezones