# how to filter spetember in datefield django?

Tags: django

Hope You Are Good

I Have This Model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ....
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

now I want to get only September tasks

not matter what date is, I want to filter or grep September 2020 tasks

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django filter current month data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138862/django-filter-current-month-data)

Comment: @urbanespaceman yes. that's was my question answer thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
month_code = 9     # September
tasks = Task.objects.filter(timestamp__month=month_code)
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#month)